# Reverse proxy styles missing

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

According to this referral i have implemented reverse proxy in my apache server.

```
ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
```

Pages from the origin server is fetching but styles are missing.I have loaded the following modules in `httpd.conf` file.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Anyone have an idea what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

We need to give reverse proxy matching to the css/js file directories also.

```
ProxyPass "/foo/static/css or js" "http://foo.example.com/static/css or js directory"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo/static/css or js " "http://foo.example.com/css or js directory"
```